# List of msbuild properties TFS passes to a build script

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I'm looking for a page that lists all msbuild properties that TFS passes to a build script and I can't find it.

Thanks

Pawel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Customizable Team Foundation Build Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337598.aspx)

[30 Useful Team Build Properties](http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/30_useful_team.html)

Comment: It looks like those lists are no longer valid for TFS2013. The detailed build logs I'm seeing indicate the only things being passed in 2013 are SkipInvalidConfigurations, OutDir, VCBuildOverride, BuildId, BuildLabel, BuildTimestamp, BuildSourceVersion, and BuildDefinition. Not exactly a wealth of riches, alas.

Comment: A list of TeamBuild parameters for TFS2013 can be found in the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets file in %programfiles%\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild (on a 64-bit system).