# How can I refer to the workspace path from msbuild in team build?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I've got a boatload of legacy project files that use a $(ProjectRoot) variable in include paths to refer to the root of the source tree. We define the variable in our visual studio environment so desktop builds can find their way to the tfs workspace in use.

I would like to define this variable in the Team Build environment via an MSBuild command line option in my tfs build definition, but I can't seem to find a way that works. I found an answer ([List of msbuild properties TFS passes to a build script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287312/list-of-msbuild-properties-tfs-passes-to-a-build-script)) with a list of variables and SolutionRoot looked promising.

When I put `/p:ProjectRoot=$(SolutionRoot)` in the `MSBuild Arguments` for my build definition, ProjectRoot ends up empty. I want it to expand to something like  `D:\Builds\18\TfsProject\BuildDef\src\`

Is there a way to define my variable with the value of the root of the workspace sources in Team Build?

Note: I tried to figure this out in TFS2010 and finally gave up and modified the BuildProcessTemplate to define the variable using the SourcesDirectory variable that's available inside that context. I thought I'd take another run at it in the hopes of using the new template in TFS2013 without modification, but I'm still stumped.

**UPDATE**: Turns out the syntax I had in my MSBuild Arguments would work if the variable I'm dereferencing were actually being passed to msbuild. The list from the other post I reference seems to no longer be valid. Looking at the detailed Team Build logs, it looks like the only variables being passed in to msbuild in Team Build are OutDir, BuildId, BuildLabel, BuildTimestamp, BuildSourceVersion, and BuildDefinition. None of those gives me the info my current msbuild scripts need at build time so I'm stuck with either reworking all our project files or continuing with the BuildProcessTemplate modifications I've been using. Unless someone comes along with a better answer here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to specify `/p:ProjectRoot=$(TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY)` in the MSBuild Arguments of your build definition when using TFS2013.

See [the Team Foundation Build environment variables documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850448.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Set the property using the other property.  Use condition to only set it if its empty.

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="xxxxxxxxxxxx">


    <PropertyGroup>
        <ProjectRoot Condition="$(ProjectRoot)==''"/>$(SolutionRoot)</ProjectRoot>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: That would work if I wanted to edit the scores of project files where I need the value available. (And if we fix the typos: should be ==, not =, and the slash before the closing angle bracket of the opening ProjectRoot tag is redundant. I tried to edit the comment to correct these, but the edit's been in peer review for 5 days now so...)

Comment: I fixed the ==.  I was going from memory on the PropertyGroup.  Yeah, you might have to pay the piper.